# Dart: What the <type> after the function name does

Tags: dart

Why does this code works? Can't understand why this code works just fine even though the function asks for `int`.

```
void main(){      
  String imprimir = "abc";  

  imprime(imprimir);

}

void imprime<int>(int aa){   //works, but stops working if we remove <int> as it should
  print(aa);  
}
```

What does the `<type>` after the name of a function does and means?

Comment: See https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics.  You've created a generic function.  Its type parameter, which can be named almost anything, reuses the name `int` and hides the actual `int` integer type.  If you remove `<int>`, the function is no longer generic and will expect an actual `int` argument.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So it basically just disable the `int` in `int aa`?. Does it mean I shouldn't define the parameter's type in this case, is it useless?

Comment: As your code currently is, the generic type (which happens to be named `int`) is inferred to be `String` when you call it.  In your case, `imprime` doesn't need to be generic and could be just `void imprime(String aa)`.  If you do want to pass it different argument types, then you should give the generic type a better name (e.g. `void imprime<T>(T aa)`).

Comment: I think I got it. So this pattern is just useful with generic types. Basically when I need a generic type in the parameter I have to declare it after the function's name creating so a generic function.